# Take selected parts of a conversation and bookmark it in Chat

Tags: feature-request, chat, conversation, chat-bookmarks

Currently the "Bookmark a conversation" feature is great. It provides just what a user needs in a busy chat room; get in, get the important stuff from the bookmarks and get out.

Though sometimes, these bookmarked conversations have a lot of extra stuffing in it. Chit Chat. Sometimes 100-300 messages is a lot to scroll through in chat.

So is it possible to get an *abridged* "Bookmark a conversation" feature such that one can mark messages selectively to put into a bookmarked conversation? This is similar to how a [summary of a SE Podcast](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/12/se-podcast-30-robert-cartaino-rebecca-chernoff/) occurs in blog.stackoverflow.com. You get the points from there a lot faster than reading through the bookmark (yes I realize the Podcast is not a good example because Joel and Alex talks).

[image: Podcast Room]

For example in the above it would be great to deselect some of the messages before saving it in the bookmarks.

Basically a bookmark feature to get all the meat but none of the fat.